# Error inyección dependencias en servicio symfony 4. Too few arguments to function NewUser:: 0 passed in RegistrationController.php 2 expected

Tags: php7, symfony4, inyeccion-de-dependencias

Estoy intentando configurar la inyección de dependencias para un servicio "Newuser". Para en un futuro no depender de mysql lo que hecho es crear un servicio "mysqlService" que implementa una interfaz con el método "persist". Desde el controlador instancio el caso de uso "NewUser" que en su constructor inyectando la interfaz de "DatabaseServiceInterface" y otro servicio "UserPasswordEncoderInterface". No funciona correctamente ya que symfony se queja porque "NewUser no recibe nada como parámetro" (Cuando debería inyectarse automáticamente el servicio).

Los ficheros son los siguientes.

DataBaseServiceInterface:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Application\Infraestructure\DatabaseService;



Interface DatabaseServiceInterface
{
    public function persist(Object $ormObject):void;
}
```

MysqlService:

```
<?php

namespace App\Application\Infraestructure\DatabaseService;


use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;


class MysqlService implements DatabaseServiceInterface
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function persist(Object $ormObject):void{
        $this->entityManager->persist(ormObject);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }


}
```

Caso de uso NewUser:

```
<?php

namespace App\Application\AppUseCases\User\NewUser;



use App\Application\Infraestructure\DatabaseService\DatabaseServiceInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class NewUser {

    private $dabaseService;
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(
        DatabaseServiceInterface $dabaseService,
        UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder
    ) {
        $this->dabaseService = $dabaseService;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function execute(NewUserRequest $userRegisterRequest) {

        //Encode the plain password
        $userRegisterRequest->user->setPassword(
            $this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
                $userRegisterRequest->user,
                $userRegisterRequest->password
            )
        );

        $userRegisterRequest->user->setEmail($userRegisterRequest->email);
        $userRegisterRequest->user->setRoles(array_unique(['ROLE_USER']));

        //crear servicio para mysql
        $this->dabaseService->persist($userRegisterRequest->user);

    }

}
```

Services.yaml

```
# This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
# Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones

    #App\Application\Infraestructure\DatabaseService\DatabaseServiceInterface:
     #   autowire: true


    App\Application\Infraestructure\DatabaseService\DatabaseServiceInterface: '@database_service'
    database_service:
        class: App\Application\Infraestructure\DatabaseService\MysqlService
        autowire: true
        public: true
    App\Application\Infraestructure\DatabaseService\MysqlService: '@mysql_service'
    mysql_service:
        class: App\Application\Infraestructure\DatabaseService\MysqlService
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']
        autowire: true
        public: true
    App\Application\AppUseCases\User\NewUser\NewUser: '@newuser_service'
    newuser_service:
        class: App\Application\AppUseCases\User\NewUser\NewUser
        arguments: ['@database_service','@security.user_password_encoder.generic']
        autowire: false
        public: true
```

RegistrationController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Application\AppUseCases\User\NewUser\NewUserRequest;
use App\Application\Domain\User\User;
use App\Application\Infraestructure\DatabaseService\MysqlService;
use App\Form\RegistrationFormType;
use App\Application\Infraestructure\User\UserAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\GuardAuthenticatorHandler;
use App\Application\AppUseCases\User\NewUser\NewUser;

class RegistrationController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/register", name="app_register")
     */
    public function register(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder, GuardAuthenticatorHandler $guardHandler, UserAuthenticator $authenticator): Response
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {


            $newUserRequest = new NewUserRequest($user, $form->get('email')->getData(), $form->get('plainPassword')->getData());
            $newUser = new NewUser();
            $newUser->execute($newUserRequest);


            return $guardHandler->authenticateUserAndHandleSuccess(
                $user,
                $request,
                $authenticator,
                'main' // firewall name in security.yaml
            );
        }

        return $this->render('registration/register.html.twig', [
            'registrationForm' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Aunque symfony no lanza ningun error porqué parece que está bien la configuración sigue sin funcionar. El error que lanza al ejecutar el caso de uso es el siguiente:

```
Too few arguments to function App\Application\AppUseCases\User\NewUser\NewUser::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/symfony/src/Controller/RegistrationController.php on line 33 and exactly 2 expected
```

Comment: Puedes poner el código del registrationController?

Comment: @jakala si claro, lo añado arriba

Comment: El error te está diciendo que al hacer un `new NewUser()` espera que le pases dos parámetros pero no le estás pasando ninguno. Puedes revisar el constructor de la clase NewUser?

Comment: Si justo estos parámetros son servicios que quiero inyectar. ¿Entiendo que no debería ser necesario que los pasara por parámetro al instanciar?

Comment: Creo que estás confundido.tal como lo tienes, lo que debes hacer es inyectar los servicios en el controller (o cogerlos con $this->get('nombre_servicio') y luego al llamar al constructor de NewUser() pasarlo como parámetro. Pero es mala práctica lo que estás haciendo. Los modelos no deben tener lógica de negocio. Es el handler correspondiente el que debe tener dichos servicios, ejecutarlos y luego crear el NewUser asignando los valores correspondientes

Comment: Me expliclo. Lo que estoy intentando hacer es inyectar estos servicios dentro NewUser sin necesidad de pasar por parámetro estos servicios. NewUser no es un modelo. Estoy usando NewUser como caso de uso. Viene a ser un servicio de aplicación. Igual no he hecho bien algo, pero hasta donde entiendo en la documentación no debería quejarse symfony al instanciar NewUser e inyectar los servicios automáticamente en el constructor e NewUser. Pero no lo consigo

Comment: Ok. No funciona así. Para lo que quieres hacer, NewUser debe iniciarse como un servicio. Revisa como configurar un servicio en symfony, y me la configuración puedes inyectar esos servicios que te interesan dentro de tu servicio. Tal como lo tienes ahora es una clase con un constructor que te exige pasarle los servicios como parsmetro

Comment: Ahora mismo actualizo la información, también he probado a definir mi servicio NewUser configurando los parámetros. Tampoco me funciona. Gracias por la información volveré a probarlo y revisar

Comment: Revisando la documentación, no hace falta que defina ningún servicio en principio. Igualmente he definido el servicio en el services.yaml. Pero tampoco funciona correctamente. Según reza en este punto, el autowire se encarga de cargar los servicios y favorece la inyección automática. ¿A alguien se le ocurre que puede estar pasando? https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/service_container.html